# MobX: getting data into the store from another store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I use this construction for form store and validate: https://medium.com/@KozhukharenkoN/react-form-validation-with-mobx-8ce00233ae27

There is a store form:

```js
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx'
import FormStore from './FormStore'

import UserStore from 'stores/UserStore'

class SettingsFormStore extends FormStore {
  @observable
  form = {
    fields: {
      email: {
        value: UserStore.email,
        defaultValue: UserStore.email,
        error: null,
        rule: 'required|email'
      },
    },
    meta: {
      isValid: true,
      error: null,
    },
  }
}

export default new SettingsFormStore()
```

there is a stor user:

```js
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx'

import * as UserAPI from 'api/UserAPI'

class UserStore {
  @observable id
  @observable email

  constructor() {
    this.load()
  }

  @action setValues(values) {
    this.id = values.id
    this.email = values.email
  }

  @action removeValues() {
    this.id = null
    this.email = null
  }

  load() {
    UserAPI.getMe()
      .then(result => {
        this.setValues(result.user)
      })
  }
}

export default new UserStore()
```

In the form component I get email from store:

```
const email = SettingsFormStore.form.fields.email.value
```

but email some reason undefied, although UserStore.email keeps the value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reaction(
  () => ({ email: UserStore.email, id: UserStore.id }),
  ({ email, id }) => {
    this.form.fields.email.value = email
    ...
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
constructor() {
     super()

     reaction(
       () => UserStore.email,
       email => {
         this.form.fields.email.value = email
       }
     )   
}
```

Comment: But there is question: How to use several parameters from UserStore in one reaction?